# How to find git commit number on branch/tag and how to find commit id by number?

Tags: git

How can I find the total number of commits on a branch?

(This is usefull when having setting versionnumber on apps etc)

---

How can I reverse that number to find a commit id?

(This is usefull when you need to debug an app with versionnumber same as commit number).

Comment: In general: don't. Find some other way to obtain a version number that doesn't assume a linear history.

Comment: Better to explicitly tag your releases with _git tag_ than to rely on being able to calculate the commit in some way.

Comment: I'm not sure if I can type both numbers and letters in version number on e.g. iOS/Mac apps. Yep, git tag is great. Using that. Our purpose of the git number is mostly when testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find number of commits on branch or tag (leave blank if current branch is desired):

```
$ git log <branch/tag/blank> --pretty=oneline | wc -l
```

Will output e.g.

```
5164
```

---

Find commit id by commit number (replace 5614 with your commit number)

```
$ git log <branch/tag/blank> --pretty=oneline --reverse | sed -n 5614p
```

Will output e.g.

```
e5c303d47afb7c3a98bc138049024d24924e6a9b Minor code fixes
```

Comment: I've heard 'rev-list' is better for this purpose than 'log'.. anyone feel free to update

Comment: Note that using (only) the number of commits on a branch to set the version number is a really bad idea. That's e.g. because when you do a new release from a different branch, the number of commits might actually be the same as for the original release. The output of [git describe](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-describe.html) is suited much better to be part of a version number.

Comment: Ok. interesting. I will need to look more into that.